# consuming data from RabbitMQ via Spring

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am new to rabbitMQ and want to receive messages from Queue so that I can provide it to internal Queue and work on the messages in parallel. I want to acknowledge queue depending upon the messages. Source is providing single message at a time and that would take a lot of time to process messages. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Spring AMQP Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/).

There's also a Spring Boot [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/).